# tomcat webapp failover

Tags: tomcat, high-availability, failover, failovercluster

I am working on the high availability aspect of a webapp deployed in tomcat. I require a mechanism for failover such that it should not be apparent to the webapp user and have am looking at tomcat clustering as a solution for the same.

If I am looking only at failover and not on load balancing(not required at this point) , how should I **configure** the tomcat cluster ?

EDIT

I am aware about the mechanism but am looking at the **configuration aspect.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for this myself, I finally found https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/loadbalancers.html, look for "configure hot spare workers" under "Advanced Load Balancer Worker Properties"

Comment: That link seems to be dead now :(