# Tomcat active passive failover

Tags: tomcat, failovercluster

I'm trying to make my application highly available using **active/passive** method. I currently deploy the application on a Tomcat server, which could either be hosted on Windows or Linux platform.

So, now I deploy it on two Tomcat servers. Each server runs on a separate machine. I configure the Tomcats to be of the same cluster via Tomcat configuration which gives me session replication (storing in DB). I use some web server / load balancer to redirect requests (not decided yet).

The problem is that the application *cannot run simultaneously on both Tomcats* since it is currently stateful (and it's too costly to make it stateless). I actually need that only *one* Tomcat will be up at the same time. Or, for the least, that only one application will be started on a Tomcat.

To sum it up, I need a software that can:

1. Identify invalid state of application via HTTP request (either machine/Tomcat is down or application is otherwise unresponsive);
2. Start Tomcat instance or application on Tomcat when the other application is identified as invalid;
3. Stop Tomcat instance or application on Tomcat when it's identified as invalid.
4. Support both Linux and Windows platforms...

This product can be a library that's used on our JVM, it may be separate monitoring processes that reside on the Tomcats machines and communicate with each-other and with the Tomcats, it may use our DB. It may use the web server machine...

I searched for off-of-the-shelf products that do it ([Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Pacemaker)/[CoroSync](http://www.corosync.org/)/[keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/)), all not supporting Windows (as far as I understand).

Comment: look at my answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465714/tomcat-webapp-failover - might solve your problem

Comment: Might be a good reason to look at a clusterable application server, where the nodes know of one another.  Glassfish 3.1.2 might be usable to you in the open source edition.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen hope you didn't read my own answer here :) (many words there). Anyway, it's interesting to know that Glassfish supports clustering but replacting our servers wasn't acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: I did.  A lot of work to make Tomcat do something it was not designed to do.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and I wept. If our services were stateless, though, we'd just make it all active-active and go to sleep happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

Both Tomcats are always started. The application is also started on both of the Tomcats.

A special `synchronization service` was hand-written. This service is part of the application and started along with the application startup. It is responsible for determination of the node that is currently active and which one *should* be active.

My application used a Spring context for managing my services lifecycle. I separated it into two different contexts: a `wrapper` Spring context and a `child` Spring context.

The `wrapper` context was started along with the application startup, always available and working on both Tomcats. The synchronization service was configured as a bean in the `wrapper` context.

The `child` context actually included all services that my application provided for external clients. *This* is the context that I designated to be started only when current node is active and stopped when becoming passive.

**How was the `child` context swithched on / off when active / passive?**

This context wasn't started automatically along the application startup. When the `synchronization service` concluded that the current node should become active, an event was raised that caused the `child` context to get started, thus making all services *available* on that node. And the other way around: when the `synchronization service` concluded that the current node shuold become passive, a proper event was raise that caused the `child` context to shutdown, making all services *unavailable* on that node.

Another important feature that was added was an `interceptor` for incoming requests. An incoming request hitting the one of the Tomcats, actually implies that the load balancer / web server has decided that the target node *is the currently available or preferred node*. In such a case, even if it happened that the target node was the passive one, it *should* now become active. So the `intercepror` would raise the same event that the `synchronization service` did, again making the `child` context to start and the services available on that node (and the `synchronization serivce`s on both Tomcats identified the switch and the formerly active node would passivate).